# Which Facebook Developer Roles do I need to submit Request for App Review?

Tags: facebook

I have given access to my developer with the roles "Developer" on Facebook User Roles.

He tells me that he needs "Admin" Role in order to submit for review.

I don't necessarily want him to have Admin access, so is there any easy way?

Comment: Submit for review yourself, with your own admin acount?

Comment: @CBroe Yes that I can do - but the problem is he can not even add add any permission, as the "Developer" does not have this right.

Comment: Well then you will have to make up your mind, whether you trust them to make _administrative_ changes to your app and its settings … or whether you want _all_ of that to go through you.